# How to generate a single key-press event signal with tkinter.bind method

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, signals

I have a simple ui, which should print every key that I've pressed.
I need to generate signal **once** per real key-press.
How can I achieve that?
In default, tkinter generates signal once, than waits about 0.5 sec and starts generate signal in loop, until *KeyRelease* event happens.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200, bg="white")
    frame.pack()

    def key_handler(event):
        print(event.char, event.keysym, event.keycode)
        return 'break'

    root.bind('<Key>', key_handler)

    root.mainloop()
```

Using 'break' at the end of the bond function doesn't stop the next event-call.

In addition (bc this is a minor question, which is too small for separate post), how can I create these key sequences?:

- "Shift" and some digit
- some digit and '+' or '-' symbol

**UPD**:
I don't really want to do this:

```
def key_handler(event):
    global eve
    if eve != event.keysym:
        eve = event.keysym
        print(event.char, event.keysym, event.keycode)
```

because signal still process when I want to remove it at all. But, I don't really know how much affect does Dummy signal on the program in total, so may be this solution makes sense?

**UPD with some solutions from users:**
I've append the answer in question body because I've accidentally closed the question before adding my answer, so here it is:

Here is the example with **bind/unbind solution**:

```
class KeyHandler:
    def __init__(self, key: str):
        self.func_id = root.bind(f'<KeyPress-{key}>', self.key_press)
        root.bind(f'<KeyRelease-{key}>', self.key_release)

    def key_release(self, event: Event):
        print('released', event.char)
        self.func_id = root.bind(f'{event.char}', self.key_press)

    def key_press(self, event: Event):
        print('pressed', event.char)
        root.unbind(f'{event.char}', self.func_id)

KeyHandler('1')
KeyHandler('2')
KeyHandler('3')
KeyHandler('4')

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the example with simple **state check solution** (handling all events which are connected with current key, may cause event spam):

```
keys = []

def key_handler(event: Event):
   global keys

   if event.type is EventType.KeyPress:
       if not (event.keycode in keys):
           keys.append(event.keycode)
           print('pressed', event.char)
   elif event.type is EventType.KeyRelease:
       if event.keycode in keys:
           print('released', event.char)
           keys.remove(event.keycode)


root.bind('<KeyPress-9>', lambda e: key_handler(e))
root.bind('<KeyRelease-9>', lambda e: key_handler(e))
```

Comment: You can try unbinding the `<Key>` event inside the callback and rebind `<Key>` inside the callback of binding `<KeyRelease>`.

Comment: @pippo1980, yes, there is interesting solutions there. But some of them are system depended. Btw, some solutions includes 'state-checking' and this looks like a solution :)

Comment: I flagged question as duplicate, could help to link them toghether if anybody else has same question

Comment: @pippo1980, I've done this, but I forgot to add my own answer to the question. Can you, pls, vote to reopen the question? I just don't want to post the whole answer in the question body...

Comment: Not sure I have that power , I'll try

Comment: Nope I am 500 points short, try to contact a moderator

Comment: @Brian oakley has that power see answer below

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that tkinter can't distinguish between a single press and press-and-hold. At least, not on some systems. It could be that it's your keyboard that is passing multiple events to tkinter. That is to say, tkinter has no way to guarantee you'll only get a single press and release when the user holds a key down.

You're going to have to come up with some sort of logic to decide what is a unique, intentional keypress and what is not. You can either only report when a keypress is different from the one before, or only report a keypress if some time passes between identical keypresses, or something like that.

Without knowing what you expect to happen when a user presses and holds a key for an extended amount of time, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Bryan, thank you for your explanation! 
Can I ask you to reopen the question? I simply closed it before I answered it myself and I don't think that it will be a good idea to post the whole answer in question body now...

Comment: @mika: I don't have the ability to reopen questions.